# How to use jquery GET to fetch the content of a page once but split it and insert it into different divs?

Tags: jquery, get

Hi,

There is an external web page and its content is split into 2 divs. One is IDed #mgs and the other one #users. I want to load the content of each DIV and insert them into different DIVS on my page. I did this:

```
$("#cont1").load("page.php #mgs");
$("#cont2").load("page.php #users");
```

this works but since the external page is also on my server I see it like a waste of resources because its loading the same page twice. How can I load it only once and split the content into my 2 divs? I tried something like this:

```
$.get("page.php", function (data) {
 data = $(data).find('#mgs').html();
 data2 = $(data).find('#users').html();
           
 $("#cont1").empty().append(data);
 $("#cont2").empty().append(data2);
});
```

but it wont work. Any way around?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `data` too many times and when you get to the second `$(data).find()` it isn't the full page response any more.

Also `html(string)` will replace all existing content which is simpler than combining `empty` and `append`

Try:

```
$.get("page.php", function(data) {
  const $page = $(data),
    mgs = $page.find('#mgs').html(),
    users = $page.find('#users').html();

  $("#cont1").html(mgs);
  $("#cont2").html(users);
});
```

Comment: thank you but there must be something wrong with the syntax. The code is producing nothing.

Comment: You will need to do some basic debugging then. Start in browser dev tools and check console for errors thrown. Check in Network tab to see if request made and inspect that request to see if it is a 200 status and that response body is as expected. Start narrowing down where the issue is

Comment: I did so and kinda fixed it but I cant make so much sense out of it. Please see the edits in the code you posted.

Comment: Don't change the code in the answer to something that I would never write and doesn't make sense. Just explain your debugging findings

Comment: Well, sorry but the thing is that the code I posted does work and yours doesnt. The debug message says `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing variable name`. Does it work on your side?